# Eigenvectors, Singular Vectors, and Excel

Tags: linear-algebra, principal-component-analysis

First time asker here.

First off, I know I should be doing this in R or Python. I will. For now I'm reading a textbook, using simple examples and Excel to try to learn the concepts of linear algebra. I've got an Excel add-in from Ponderosa Computing. It displays eigenvalues and eigenvectors in ascending order, and singular values and vectors in descending order. The book says right singular vectors are the eigenvectors of ATA. I think I understand that. Here is my matrix $A$, which is a centered difference matrix (centered by column), the matrix ATA$/(n-1)$, and eigenvectors of ATA:

[image: centered difference matrix A]

[image: covar of original A, ATA/(n-1)]

[image: Eigenvectors of covariance matrix, with eigenvalues as top row]

Now here's what's getting me confused:

The right singular vectors of the difference matrix $A$ are the eigenvectors of ATA but with signs reversed. The add-in automatically displays the vs transposed, ostensibly to make the SVD math easier to see.

[image: Right singular vectors, first column singular values]

I transpose back, then multiply by an Identity matrix with rows switched in order to display the singular vectors in the same way as the above eigenvectors.

[image: Right singular vectors as computed, transpose]

[image: Right Singular vectors as columns, and manipulated Identity matrix used]

So, what's the interpretation here? I've read over and over again that right singular vectors (vs) are just the eigenvectors of ATA. But these are different vectors. I remember reading about having to change the sign of the determinant when matrices are acted on by permutation matrices (or something). Is that what's going on? Are the eigenvectors in my third image and singular vectors in my last image equally valid?

Thanks if you read this whole thing. Struggling here

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you should be doing this in python - as you said.

Comment: @jlewis What do you mean when you say "The right singular vectors of the difference matrix  are the eigenvectors of ATA but with signs reversed"? When I look at your third image and last image, I don't see any pairs of vectors with signs reversed.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Hi Ben, just looking at the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvector (third image) it starts with [.383, .336, .358] and then the singular vector corresponding to the largest singular value in the last image is [-.383, -.336, -.358]. I'm wondering if this is a weird quick in this excel thing. I'm going to load in into R and see. Thanks

Comment: @jlewis I was confused by the reverse order and the singular value being in the top row. To answer your question though, there's nothing wrong with the sign of the eigenvector being different: if $A^TAv = \lambda v$, then it's also true that $A^TA(-v) = \lambda (-v)$; if $v$ is an eigenvector, so is $-v$. Which sign you end up with just comes down to the details of the algorithm

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you so much! I kind of figured, but don't know if I can always trust my math instincts. I'll look to close the question.